# Are these two theorems about algebraic varieties the same?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, ring-theory

In Artin's *Algebra*, there is a theorem (1) stated as the following:

> Let $J\subset\Bbb{C}[x]$ be an ideal such that $J=(f_1,\cdots,f_r)$ where $f_1,\cdots,f_r\in\Bbb{C}[x_1,\cdots,x_n]$. Let $R=\Bbb{C}[x_1,\cdots,x_n]/J$. Let $V$ be the set of common zeros of $\{f_1,\cdots,f_r\}$. Then the maximal ideals of $R$ are in bijective correspondence with the points of $V$.

There is another statement (2) (I don't remember where I learned it from) I've seen before:

> Let $V\subset{C}^n$ be a variety. Then there is a bijective correspondence between points in $V$ and maximal ideals in ${\Bbb C}[x_1,\cdots,c_n]/I(V)$, where
>   $$
> I(V):=\{f\in{\Bbb C}[x_1,\cdots,x_n]:\forall x\in V\ \ f(x)=0\}
> $$
>   is an ideal.

Here are my questions:

- Are these two statements the same?
- Can anyone come up with a reference for (2)? (If I state (2) in a wrong way, can somebody correct it?)

---

I know almost nothing about algebraic geometry and commutative algebra. I came up with this question when I read Artin's *Algebra*, in which there is a small section about algebraic geometry. I suspect that (2) is different from (1). Suppose in (2) $V$ is the set of common zeros of $\{f_1,\cdots, f_r\}$. Then $I(V)$ might be strictly bigger than $(f_1,\cdots, f_r)$.

---

The definition of algebraic variety $V\subset{\Bbb C}^n$ I use here (in Artin's book) is the set of common zeros of finitely many polynomials in $n$ variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, these are the same theorems, basically. The theorem that ties the two together is the following (Nullstellensatz):

**Theorem:** There is a bijection between radical ideals $I\subseteq \mathbb{C}[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ (that is, ideals that satisfy $I=\{f\in \mathbb{C}[x_1,\ldots,x_n]:f^r\in I\mbox{ for some }r\in\mbox{N}\}$) and sets that are of the form
$$\{a=(a_1,\ldots,a_n)\in \mathbb{C}^n:g_1(a)=\cdots=g_s(a)=0\}$$
for certain polynomials $g_1,\ldots,g_s$, given by $I\mapsto V(I)$, where $V(I)$ denotes the zero set of the polynomials in $I$.

The inverse map above is given by $\Phi:X\mapsto\{f\in \mathbb{C}[x_1,\ldots,x_n]:f(x)=0\mbox{ for all }x\in X\}$.

Basically, if $J$ is an ideal in $\mathbb{C}[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$, then $\Phi(V(J))=\mbox{rad}(J)$, where
$$\mbox{rad}(J)=\{f\in\mathbb{C}[x_1,\ldots,x_n]:f^r\in J\}.$$
Now the idea that ties your two theorems together is the following:

*The maximal ideals of $\mathbb{C}[x_1,\ldots,x_n]/J$ are in bijection with the maximal ideals of $\mathbb{C}[x_1,\ldots,x_n]/\mbox{rad}(J)$*.

**Proof:** Since $J\subseteq\mbox{rad}(J)$, if $\frak{m}$ is a maximal ideal that contains $\mbox{rad}(J)$, then $\frak{m}$ contains $J$. We must show that the converse is true. If $\frak{m}$ contains $J$, let $f\in\mbox{rad}(J)$. Then $f^r\in J$ for some $J$, and therefore $f^r\in \frak{m}$. Since $\frak{m}$ is prime, we have that $f$ must be in $\frak{m}$. $\Box$

Comment: As I see from the strong nullstellensatz, $J$ in (1) are different from $I(V)$ in (2). How does the nullstellensatz make (1) and (2) the same?

Comment: The point is that they're not the same; we have that $I(V(J))=\mbox{rad}(J)$. For example, take $J=(x^2)$ in $\mathbb{C}[x]$. Then $V(J)=\{x\in\mathbb{C}:x^2=0\}=\{0\}$, and so $I(V(J))=(x)$. However, the maximal ideals that contain $J$ and $I(V(J))$ are the same, and so we have the bijection I put above.

Comment: Fair enough. The first theorem you quoted is the strong nullstellensatz. I was confused by the second proposition that you also call it nullstellensatz.

Comment: You first say "The theorem that ties the two together is the folloing (Nullstellensatz)". And then you say "Now the idea that ties your two theorems together is the following (Nullstellensatz)".

Comment: Dear @Jack: Sorry about that! I only meant to put it on the first theorem but I think I accidentally copied and pasted it on the second one too. I edited the answer.